# c# databinding form title

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm trying to DataBind the Form Title.

I have the following class which controls the App title:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _titulo_app;
        public string titulo_app
        {
            get {
                    return _titulo_app;
                }

            set {   _titulo_app = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("titulo_app");
                }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propiedad)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propiedad));
            }
        }
    }
```

In Form_Load event I have:

```
// Inicialización de estados....
myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.titulo_app = "The title of the app";
```

Well, in Design mode, I click on the Form for setting the DataBindings properties.

In **Text**, I setup the **titulo_app** from the above class property and in advanced options i set the onPropertyChange from the dropDown list for Text.

The fact is that this does not work. There's some step I'm missing using this procedure.

I know that I can make this work by adding the following line:

```
this.DataBindings.Add("Text", myclass, "titulo_app");
```

The question is that I do not understand how can i get it working using the settings?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using WPF?

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms.